# Renewing contract/employment, when should you ask for a raise

Tags: human-resources, contracts, raise

I'm currently working as a programming and developement coop student for a large FI in Canada. At the end of the month my contract will end and I will be 're-hired' as a part time employee while I finish my degree.

**When should I ask for a raise?**

For example:

- Right away
- When deciding the new work schedule
- When the official offer is presented (counter offer)

For this question to help as many as possible please assume that I do deserve the raise.

Im currently between examples two and three, we have a rough schedule, and Im waiting on documents from HR. Should I run over to my boss and ask now before the documents can be finalized? Or wait and counter offer?

Comment: Although my problem has been solved I'm going to wait a day or two before accepting an answer in the hopes of a more generally applicable answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Normally you renegotiate as part of the new contract (temp or perm) negotiations.

The fact you say you will be "rehired" implies that the deal is already done as it sounds like they've already agreed terms for you to stay on (possibly implied by you not saying anything)

You should raise it now, but be prepared, it could change the deal, and you might not be hired to the part time role if your request is outwith their plans.

Answer (score 3):

Certainly the explicit renegotiation should be part of the new contract negotiations, prior to agreeing to the contract.  However, you should take steps to ensure that both your request is not a surprise to them, and that you fully understand the financial terms of the employment arrangement.

In particular, if you were a contractor before and not an employee, do not be surprised if the employee rate is actually lower than the contractor (as the benefits/taxes may be higher for a full employee, even part time).  (Note, this is true in the US, not sure about Canada.)

Either way, you should do what you can to ensure both you and your boss know what the other expects in an informal environment before you get to a formal negotiation, especially if that negotiation is with a HR recruiter rather than your direct boss.  In addition to not surprising him/her, you also give your boss a chance to make sure the budget has room for your salary increase.

On your end, perhaps prior to talking to your boss, you should find out if there are other employees who have been similar situations in the past, and whether a salary increase was automatic, or even possible.  (Your coworkers may not feel comfortable talking numbers, but likely they will at least be willing to tell you the possibility of an increase.)  Given you're at a large company and in a common role there, it seems likely there should be some past history available to you to help guide your expectations, and to give you some ammunition (but don't name names unless they give you permission to do so).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have a good relationship with your boss, run over to your boss and ask them the same question you are asking us. Further, ask your boss to suggest a percentage raise that you could request - the accent is on 'request' not 'demand'  and have a fair chance that the request will be well received. And ask how your boss how to go about making that request.

Comment: I've actually done just that, he said to wait until the details from HR arrive and we can sit down to discuss them :)

Comment: @RyanS Sounds like a plan. Your boss should be much more attuned to the nuances than we are. And  if you are asking for anything, you are better off asking for it with your boss's backing you up.